# Logo floating over or above header

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the header for my application using HTML and CSS. I am currently using the jQuery UI for layout. What I am trying to do is to have the logo fit better in my web application. As of right now, the logo is inline with the text and automatically re-sized the header, which I do not want. I would like to have the logo its separate entity that floats over (or above) the header. I think it is feasible in CSS but not quite sure how.

```
<div class="ui-layout-north">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/cal_fire_logo.gif"></a>
        Hi
    </div>
</div>
```

Previously I tried the following CSS to try getting close to what I intend to do but it does not quite achieve my hopes:

```
 .ui-layout-north {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 100px;
}

.ui-layout-north .logo {
    line-height: 100px;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 50%;
    width: 150px;
    left: -75px;
    top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If any of you could help that would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: An actual demo would make this easier. Check out jsFiddle or CodePen. You are probably better off setting the container to `position: relative` and the logo to `position: absolute`.

Comment: I dont really know how to recreate my situation better than this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=B89e9N4keC) since I cannot recreate my entire app in Jsfiddle.  I think share a screen shot would be best. Basically half of the logo (relative position) disappears under my center panel. I would like the logo to float above

Comment: `<div class="ui-layout-north">
        <div class="container" style="position:relative;">
            <a href="#"><img class="logo" style="position:absolute; margin:0 50%; left:-30px;" src="images/cal_fire_logo.gif"></a>
            Hi
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-west">...</div><div class="ui-layout-center"></div>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CSS for your logo you have declared your margin twice.  Your last margin setting is going to override your first one.  Not sure what you mean by it's disappearing under your center panel.  I've recreated your code on jsfiddle with a generic 150 x 100 logo pic and your code using only the first `margin:0 50%;` .  Here's a link
http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/1ut4ts76/
Let me know what you'd like it to look like instead of how it appears

Comment: That is it. I also had to add to JQuery layout UI a line of JS script:"myLayout.allowOverflow('north'); That was why my logo was hiding behind the panels adjacent to the header. Thank you.